# Pie chart labels in c# for text and percentage

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to label my pie chart with the name of the column value (which in this case would be the machine name, and the percentage next to it. This is quite difficult by default in c#. I'm taking data from a MySql database and plotting it based on the column "machine". Below is the code I currently have which will only displays the percentage:

```
string DatabaseCountMachines = "SELECT Machine, COUNT(*) total FROM completed GROUP BY Machine";

MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(DatabaseCountMachines, conDataBase);
MySqlDataReader StatsbyMachine;

try
{
    conDataBase.Open();
    StatsbyMachine = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

    while (StatsbyMachine.Read())
    {
        this.chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(StatsbyMachine.GetString("Machine"), StatsbyMachine.GetString("total"));
        this.chartMachine.Series["Series1"].CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside";
        this.chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Label = "#LEGENDTEXT" + "#PERCENT";      
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: In a Pie Chart the x-values do not apply. (You might as well use `AddY`) Can you show an image of what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a **Pie Chart** the `x-values` **do not apply** so they don't show... You might as well use `AddY`.

Simply add both data to the `Label` of each `DataPoint`!

Change

```
chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Points
            .AddXY(StatsbyMachine.GetString("Machine"), StatsbyMachine.GetString("total"));
```

to

```
int index = chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(StatsbyMachine.GetString("total"));
chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Points[index].Label = 
      StatsbyMachine.GetString("Machine") + " : " + StatsbyMachine.GetString("total");
```

Do note that while the strings you add as y-values will get converted to numbers this would not apply to x-values even if you use a chart type that uses x-values.

Some chart data do not need numeric x-values, like Names, Cities or even IDs so the will not be automatically converted, even where they could be.

Y-values otoh always need to be numeric or else the whole idea of charting makes no sense. Therefore your `string total`  will be converted to numbers, if at all possible. Where the conversion fails the values will be `0`..

Comment: I am getting an error with this code that says Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint. The link shows an example of what I'm trying to do: http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/pie-and-doughnut-charts/configuring-pie-and-doughnut-charts.html

Comment: I changed 'StatsbyMachine.GetString("total")' to ' #PERCENT'. Works perfectly. Great job.

Comment: I know this question has been answered @TaW, but when I switched to SQL format the "total" throws an error saying cannot convert from string to int. But in MySQL it doesn't.

Comment: What throws, the sql or c#?

Comment: Sorry @TaW. The c# code has the "total" underlined in red with that statement but nothing else.

Comment: Maybe the data types are different in the new sql reader? Hard to tell from here..

Comment: I eventually solved it by using the GetOrdinal like so: int index = chartMachine.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(StatsbyMachine.GetValue(StatsbyMachine.GetOrdinal("total")));